# Response variable out of range -> using gamlss in r LOGNO

Tags: r, regression, gamlss

I am new to the function GAMLSS in r, and when I run my code I always get this error: `Response Variable out of range`

After looking into the data frame, I realized the issue was one of response variables was 0.0000.

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why 0 is out of range and possible solutions to go around it (ex. such as replacement the values)?

Answer (score 0):

`LOGNO` family corresponds to the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), which is defined for **positive values** only.

The possible solutions might be (but highly depend on the context):

- use another distribution, which better models the response variable and allows zero values
- sometimes zero values are reported if they are below the limit of detection (LOD).
  In this case, one has a [censored data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)), and you may look for review of the methods, how to tackle it. A pragmatic approach is to substitute zeros with values like LOD/2, reviewed, for example, [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4271092/). However, it may result in a very biased estimation.